# Geom and ST_AsText(geom) gives different intersection results for same geometries

Tags: postgis, geometry, intersection, convex-hull

I am working to get the count of points intersecting with a convex hull. When I use the query in 1 it gives a count different from the count in query 2. Only difference is that in query 1 I am using directly geom whereas in 2, I am converting geom to text and back to geom using `ST_GeomFromText()`

1:

```
select count(*) from table 
where st_intersects(
        geom,
        (select st_convexhull(st_collect(geom)) a 
         from  table)
       );
```

2:

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where st_intersects(
       geom, 
       (select st_geomfromtext(
                 st_astext(
                   st_convexhull(st_collect(geom))
                   ),
                4326)
        from table)
      );
```

Does this conversion using `ST_AsText` change the geometry somehow? The reason to test this is that I need to send the convex geometry from web frontend as text and convert it to geom in PostgreSQL.

Comment: almost certainly a rounding error in the representation

Comment: any way around to resolve this ? but if I get text back from the st_geomfromtext result precision is same as initial st_astext(geom)

Comment: Could you prepare a dataset without confidential data that could be used as "table"?

Comment: Yeah, its important to note that ST_AsText does apply rounding to your original ordinates.  It does seems a bit surprising the first time one encounters this. Does anyone have an alternative utility that would dump out in textual format all the original precision of the ordinate?  that might help folks in this position.

Comment: Besides Text conversion, is geom WGS84? (not sure if st_intersects does transformations)

Comment: @JGH it tells me about the precision being lost by st_astext, but is there a solution to fix this, i cannot send geom from the front end as leaflet provides me with an array of coordinates that have to be converted in postgres later.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic yes it is WGS84

Comment: Maybe doing st_astext on the original geom as well so it also loses the same amount of precision? Nasty, I know.

Comment: One option to **reduce** the risk of such rounding is to snap all vertices to a grid (see st_snapToGrid), which you would apply 1) before storing your geometries and 2)when receiving geometries (from your webapp).

Comment: Another option is to properly export your geometries from Leaflet so that no rounding occurs (ewkb format), or not to export at all but to compute on the server side!